# jQuery File Tree not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use Jquery file Tree in an Electron app using the Node.js connector to display the fileSystem of the user;

I have the following code in my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jqueryFileTree.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" onload="window.$ = window.jQuery = module.exports;" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jqueryFileTree.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

and the following code in my main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fileSystem').fileTree({
      root: '/',
      script: 'scripts/connectors/jqueryFileTree.js',
      expandSpeed: 1000,
      collapseSpeed: 1000,
      multiFolder: false
  }, function(file) {
      alert(file);
  });
}
```

Acording to their website it should work but ends up displaying like this:

[image]

Im sure is something really obvious that im not seeing, but I can't find the problem! what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Node.js is serving `jqueryFileTree.js` as a file rather than running it in response to the request. This would point to a configuration issue with the server.